# Best way to use constructor as a function in std::transform?

Tags: c++, stl, c++20

I tried to specify just the constructor as the last argument of transform but it did not work since in C++ you can not take address of a constructor, but also signature would not match, constructor does not have return value.

I can easily wrap it in a lambda, but I wonder is there a simpler way to do this?
constructor *functor* does not look too bad, but it is not in `std::`, I would prefer some standard way of doing this(I looked into `std::allocator<T>::construct`, but signature does not match).

Here are my [attempts](https://godbolt.org/z/8fEYra):

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <utility>
    #include <iterator>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <vector>
    
    struct Square{
        explicit Square(const int a):a(a){}
        int a;
    };
    
    
    template<typename T>
    struct constructor{
    template<typename... Args>
    T operator()(Args&&... args) {
        return T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    };
    
    int main() {
      std::vector<int> ints{1,2};
      std::vector<Square> squares;
      // :( can not take address of a constructor
      //std::transform(ints.begin(), ints.end(), std::back_inserter(squares), &Square::Square);
      // :/ works, but requires manual implementation of constructor
      std::transform(ints.begin(), ints.end(), std::back_inserter(squares), constructor<Square>{});
      // :/ works, but spammy
      // std::transform(ints.begin(), ints.end(), std::back_inserter(squares), [](const int i) {return Square(i);});
    
      for (const auto square:squares){
          std::cout << square.a << std::endl;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Nothing in `std`. Your template isn't half bad. I'd just put it in a small utility library.

Comment: It would be great if `std::ranges::transform(ints, std::back_inserter(squares));`automatically works.

Comment: @康桓瑋 - Not with `back_inserter`, but you can do something like `std::ranges::copy(ints, util::back_emplacer(squares));` (see example https://wandbox.org/permlink/0XIdxf9e1bceZIjw). The key is the `operator=`. A standard back inserter expects an object reference, therefore copy initialization, but the c'tor is explicit. The limited application of `emplace` does it.

Comment: If the constructor weren't explicit, `ranges::to` would work here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/cjUJ5noI6Z67ezAR

Answer (score 3):

Limiting ourselves to standard C++20 facilities, I would suggest simply using the vector constructor taking iterators (which might require a tweak in the constructor of `Square` as stated below):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct Square{
    explicit Square(const int a):a(a){}
    int a;
};

int main() {
  std::vector<int> ints{1,2};
  std::vector<Square> squares(ints.begin(), ints.end());

  for (const auto square:squares){
      std::cout << square.a << std::endl;
  }
}
```

This is accepted by GCC/libstdc++ but I’m not 100% sure it should because the standard seems to imply that the elements referred to by the iterators must *implicitly* convertible to the `vector` `value_type` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9215695) for more details), and your constructor is `explicit`.

Future revisions of the standard are expected to gain `ranges::to`. The current proposal [P1206R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1206r2.pdf) has an example suggesting that the types of the input range elements must be `ConvertibleTo` the type of the elements in the container, and that concept isn’t satisfied if you only have an `explicit` constructor.

In fact, the range-v3 implementation of `ranges::to` requires the constructor to be a converting constructor for your example to work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

struct Square{
    /*explicit*/ Square(const int a):a(a){}
    int a;
};

int main() {
  std::vector<int> ints{1,2};
  std::vector<Square> squares = ints | ranges::to<std::vector<Square>>();

  for (const auto square:squares){
      std::cout << square.a << std::endl;
  }
}
```